# Changing character set of MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a MySQL table `CHINESE` with `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1` and it has a column `NAME` with `CHARACTER SET latin1`. I have huge amount to data stored in this table. Around a million rows. And, I want to execute the following commands on my database: 
`ALTER DATABASE <DATABASE_NAME> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8` 
`ALTER TABLE CHINESE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8` 
`ALTER TABLE CHINESE MODIFY NAME VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8`

Considering the fact that I have huge amount of data stored in this database. Should I run these commands on my database? Will these commands lock the database in any way?

I am using Java to query and insert values in database. Will appending `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in URI string help me?

Comment: It will take a lot of time and will not do what you expect it to do. Character set on a table is a default character set for newly created columns. And if the data in a column is stored in a wrong character set, simply changing the character set won't help, you need to fix data as well.

Comment: @newtover: I know I will have to take care of old data. I just want to make sure that the new data which I get is correct. I only want to change the character set of "NAME" column. Please suggest any alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

It will take a long time, 
I think is it is the best that you export a .sql out and don't the trans-code there replace latin1 to utf8 , then import back in a temp table. Finally swap the name of they.

Comment: I am using Java to query and insert values in database. Will appending "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" in URI string help me?